# sort a field in my table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, stored-procedures

I have a set of data like this:

```
ID | Name | Code
1  | John | ygkj
2  | Mike | ghyy
3  | Jay  | uuja
```

And I want to use a function/stored procedure to change the "Code" column into the following:

```
ID | Name | Code
1  | John | gjky
2  | Mike | ghyy
3  | Jay  | ajuu
```

Or maybe throwing it as a result of a SELECT statement. How can I do it with MySQL?

Thanks!!

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, what have you tried so far?

Comment: exporting it to excel and doing the business there, but it was useless... VBA sucks. My next try is doing it with PHP, but I'd prefer doing everything inside the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've done it via PHP. If anyone needs it, I'll post my script here

```
$inorder = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("select ID, Code from top");
while ($line = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $stringParts = $line['Code'])
    sort(str_split($stringParts);
    $inorder[$line['ID']] = implode('',$stringParts);
}
foreach($inorder as $k=>$l)
{
    $mysqli->query("update codes SET Code = '".$l."' where id_top = ".$k);
}
```

It seems like MySQL doesn't have complex array operations to work with the data within the results.